# How to create a blurry circle in the background in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to create something like this in the background with the native blur of Circle and not with a PNG.

And for that, I tried multiple ways including following codes

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    //BlurWidget()
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        ImageFiltered(
          imageFilter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 70, sigmaY: 70),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            radius: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

But the problem with this code is it's unable to expand the blur to the whole background and create a line below like [image]

I also tried a different solution and it's making the blurry circle but I don't know how to align it to a different part of the screen because align property or widget is not working in this case.

```
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                radius: 20,
              ),
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            BackdropFilter(
              filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 205.0,
                sigmaY: 205.0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```